# number_with_precision not giving back correct result for :fr locale in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, localization, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am using the following to localize a number into french-

```
number_with_precision(111.234, locale: :fr)
```

According to the [rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_with_precision) it should return-

> 111,234

as french numbers use a . and , interchangeably as compared to british english.

However i get this response -

> 111.234

There is no response in the result. I have added :fr locale in a my application.rb -

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:en, :fr]
```

Is there a reason it is not localizing my numbers? any other configuration i am missing out on?

For context i have done this in rails console -

```
pry(main)> include ActionView::Helpers
=> Object
pry(main)> number_with_precision(111.234, locale: :fr) 
=> "111.234"
```

Comment: you may need to create a locale file for french.

Comment: @pardeep Thanks alot for that! Exactly what I was missing. Thank you :) was struggling with this for a while now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing a locale file for :fr .

this is what i added in my fr.yml -

```
fr:
  number:
    format:
      delimiter: ! ','
      precision: 2
      separator: ','
      significant: false
      strip_insignificant_zeros: false
```

Works perfectly well now :)